# Take string argument from command line?

Tags: python, arguments

I need to take an optional argument when running my Python script:

```
python3 myprogram.py afile.json
```

or

```
python3 myprogram.py
```

This is what I've been trying:

```
filename = 0
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Create Configuration')
parser.add_argument('filename', type=str,
                   help='optional filename')

if filename is not 0:
    json_data = open(filename).read()
else:
    json_data = open('defaultFile.json').read()
```

I was hoping to have the filename stored in my variable called "filename" if it was provided. Obviously this isn't working. Any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please read the tutorial carefully. http://docs.python.org/howto/argparse.html

i believe you need to actually parse the arguments:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args = parser.parse_args()
```

then filename will be come available `args.filename`

Answer (score 8):

Check [sys.argv](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv). It gives a list with the name of the script and any command line arguments.

Example script:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

Calling it:

```
> python script.py foobar baz
['script.py', 'foobar', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for the first parameter `sys.argv[1]` does the trick. More info [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.argv#sys.argv).

Answer (score 1):

Try argparse's default parameter, its well documented.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Create Configuration')
parser.add_argument('--file-name', type=str, help='optional filename', 
       default="defaultFile.json")

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.file_name)
```

**Output:**

```
$ python open.py --file-name option1
option1

$ python open.py 
defaultFile.json
```

**Alternative library**:

[click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/) library for arg parsing.